# Show only populated columns of a Row

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Some Oracle V$ and DBA_* tables have large number of columns; In some cases, only very few of the columns are populated.

Example

```
         Col_1    Col_2   Col_3 .... Col_10     Col_11
          XX       YY     NULL        NULL        mm
          XX2      YY2    NULL        NULL        mm2
```

Here above table has 11 columns, but only 3 ( col_1, Col_2 & Col_11 ) have values.

Is there a script or utility available which toggles (HIDES/SHOWS) NULL columns when displaying data as follows :

```
 null_column = HIDE 

 Col_1  : XX
 Col_2  : YY
 Col_11 : mm

 <blank line>

 Col_1  : XX2
 Col_2  : YY2
 Col_11 : mm2

 null_column = SHOW

 Col_1  : XX
 Col_2  : YY
 Col_3  : NULL
 Col_4  : NULL
 Col_5  : NULL
 Col_6  : NULL
 ............
 Col_11 : mm
```

Comment: This requirement would be best handled in your presentation layer (e.g. Java, PHP, Python, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

For most database work you should use worksheets in a graphical IDE instead of scripts in a command line utility.

I'm going to go out on a limb here and guess this is a huge [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/175876) - you're asking for help with your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.  You're a DBA working on performance tuning and data analysis, and you're trying to make sense of huge amounts of unknown data using SQL*Plus.  But SQL*Plus will never be a good tool for that job.

You don't have to completely abandon SQL*Plus.  It's still a useful program for scripting installations, quick changes, or creating easily-verifiable test cases.  But programs from the 1980s cannot always handle the large amounts of data we use in 2019.

When we're looking in `V$SQL` for a performance problem, we're usually looking for something "wrong".  We don't know what that is ahead of time.  There are 98 columns in `V$SQL`, one of which is a huge CLOB.  There is simply no way to easily investigate that table without some type of graphical program that lets us scroll through the results, and click and expand  large values.  For many tasks, a simple interface like this is a thousand times better than the command line:
[image]

I say this not because I'm some awesome DBA with more skillz than anyone else.  I say this because I've worked with DBAs who knew much more about Oracle than me, but they couldn't keep up with me because they only used old-fashioned tools.

(If I'm way off, and you need this solution for a legitimate reason, I'll remove this answer.  But please explain in the question precisely why you need this solution.)

Comment: Browsing through 98 columns of V$SQL is no fun, even with TOAD or SQL*Developer. If one has to review only few rows, then Tanel Poder and Tom Kyte have a solution which can be accessed here : https://ferhatsengonul.wordpress.com/2014/12/10/pivoting-sqlplus-output-of-a-single-row-in-multiple-columns-with-column-command/

Comment: @oradbanj Even with that script you can't even see all the information in V$SQL on a single screen.  It might work well for trivial examples, but real-world SQL statements that span dozens of lines look terrible on a command line.  And comparing rows is much easier with a GUI since the values can be right next to each other.  My screenshot is a bit cutoff, but you can see that rows 3 and 4 are the same SQL statement and SQL_ID.  Those rows are 99% similar, and by scrolling and comparing the values we could tell why there are two rows for the same statement, and if it's important.